# Autocomplete-Textview with listener

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

My question is very basic, as is my experience! Sorry about the length of the post!

I am trying to create an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a listener so that I can do "stuff" when an item is selected.
The `AutoCompleteTextView` works fine, in so far as I can type in 2 characters and then select an item from the list which appears.
But the application never executes the listener code.

All my code, xml and log trace is here, so what is the simple piece that I am missing? 
I've searched all the questions and it seems to be a common problem but none of the (very few) answers work for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

SOURCE

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class A_New_StartActivity extends Activity {

private final String LOG_TAG = "CJM";
private static String result = "No result";
private static final String[] myitems =  {
"Item 1",
"Item 2",
"Item 3",
"Item 4",
"Item 5"
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Entered onCreate");

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.destination_item, myitems);
    AutoCompleteTextView itemView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_items);
    itemView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    itemView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
            result = "Selected";
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Showing Result 1");
            TextView result_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_view); 
            result_view.setText(result);
            View scroll_visibility = findViewById(R.id.result_scroll); 
            scroll_visibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            View result_visibility = findViewById(R.id.result_view); 
            result_visibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        } 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In Nothing Selected");
            result = "Nothing";
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Showing Result 2");
            TextView result_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_view); 
            result_view.setText(result);
            View scroll_visibility = findViewById(R.id.result_scroll); 
            scroll_visibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            View result_visibility = findViewById(R.id.result_view); 
            result_visibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        }
    }); 
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "completed onCreate");
}
}
```

---

MAIN.xml in R.layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</TextView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/item_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/request_item"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_items"
    android:completionThreshold="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/result_scroll"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

DESTINATION_ITEM.xml in R.layout

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

STRINGS.xml in R.values

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">A_New_Start</string>
<string name="request_item">Please enter the first 2 letters of the item</string>
<string name="result">Initialised</string>
<string name="button_text">OK</string>
```

LOG output

```
05-26 10:19:05.550: D/CJM(269): Entered onCreate

05-26 10:19:05.570: D/CJM(269): completed onCreate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting wrong Listener for AutoCompleteTextView. You have to set `addTextChangedListener()` and do the processing in the override methods of `addTextChangedListener`.

Comment: Thanks Lalit. This gives me a giant step forward in my android adventure. I still have much to learn, but this answer also gives me a better understanding of some of the vaguaries of android event processing. Thanks again!